# Content type access permission by user role

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

[image: Screen shot for Devel and content page viewed by user]

I have created 4 different content types and all except only one content type are visible to every user.  Here, I am not using any type of access module like content access, field permission or organic groups even I have also uninstalled my custom module but still could not able to find out the root cause .

In the attached screen shot 
1) The above section is permission on a node created in that content type as per user roles.
2) The below section is what, which is visible to user other than site admin.

I have also gave "View published content", "View own published content" and "View content revision" permissions (and cleared the cache) but it still not fixed.

Appreciate any guess or suggestion !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have got the issue.  This was a silly mistake, the nodes in that content types were not published.

I just published them and they are now visible to allowed roles.

Thanks